# How to enable scrolling from another controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I have 2 controllers: ViewController and GalleryViewController(with the collection view on it). From the storyboard I set for the collectionView in GalleryViewController `Scrolling Enabled` to `false`. Now, how can I change it to `true` from the `ViewController`?

I've tried this:

```
var vc: GalleryViewController?
vc.collectionView.scrollEnabled = true
```

but it does not work. Is there another solution with which I can change scrolling from another controller(ViewController)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code will create a new instance of `GalleryViewController` and you need to use the existing one.

You have a number of options, partly depending on how you navigate from `ViewController` to `GalleryViewController`.

If you are creating the Gallery View from your initial controller, then you should use `prepareForSegue`, something like this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue!.identifier == "GallerySegueOrWhateverYouHaveCalledIt" {
        let viewGalleryController:ViewGalleryController = segue!.destinationViewController as ViewGalleryController
        let collectionViewLink = viewGalleryController.collectionView
    }

}
```

If you're using a Tab Controller, and assuming you know the index of your GalleryView, let's call it `indexGalleryView`, then it's even easier

```
var vc = tabBarController!.viewControllers![indexGalleryView] as! GalleryViewController
vc.collectionView.scrollEnabled = true
```

And if you have a ViewController -> Container -> Embed GalleryViewController -> CollectionView, you can get a handle to the embedded ViewController in the viewDidLoad of the top level controller like this

```
    for vc in self.childViewControllers
    {
        if vc.isKindOfClass(GalleryViewController)
        {
            myGalleryViewController = vc as! GalleryViewController
        }
    }
```

once you have `myGalleryViewController` you should be able to access everything on the child view

Comment: no, it's an embed controller in ViewController. I think this method won't work with it =/

Comment: oh no, the ViewController is on TabBar, but GalleryVC is inside of ViewController as an embed VC

Comment: then add an outlet for the galleryVC to the ViewController and access it directly

Comment: I've putted "Container" into ViewController and inside of those container I putted `GalleryViewController`. How can I add the outlet of "GalleryVC" to VC? Sorry, it's my first time with embed controllers

Comment: because I cannot create an outlet of GalleryVC on VC by dragging

Comment: so a ViewController, containing a ContainerView, containing a CollectionViewController, or a ViewController, containing a ContainerView, containing a CollectionView?

Comment: ViewController -> Container -> Embed GalleryViewController -> CollectionView